# Java Modifying key object inside map

Tags: java, dictionary, pass-by-reference, stanford-nlp, pass-by-value

I am having a problem with JAVA map. I enter an object as a key in the map. Then I modify the key and the map does not consider the object as a key of the map any more. Even though the key inside the object has been modified accordingly.

I am working with the object `CoreLabel` from StanfordNLP but it applies to a general case I guess.

```
Map <CoreLabel, String> myMap = new HashMap...
CoreLabel key = someCreatedCoreLabel
myMap.put(key, someString)
myMap.get(key) != null ----> TRUE
key.setValue("someValue");
myMap.get(key) != null ----> FALSE
```

I hope I was clear enough. The question is why is the last statement false? I am not a very experienced programmer but I would expect it to be true. Maybe has something to do with the `CoreLabel` object?

I check if `.equals()` still holds, and it actually does

```
for(CoreLabel token: myMap.keySet()) {
     if(key.equals(token))
        System.out.println("OK");
}
```

Comment: Of course the objects will be equal. What will be different is the hashcode of the modified object and the corresponding bucket the object is in (depending on if the value changed contributes to the hashcode)

Comment: Ah ok, I understand, thanks a lot. Any work around to this? Is there a way of re-hashing?

Comment: The only way to rehash a `HashMap` is to add more elements than it currently has capacity for. This will force it to grow an recalculate its hashes. You really shouldn't do this.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will rethink the whole thing then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in modifying the value of the key, now the hash code of the key has changed as well.  A `HashMap` will first use the hash code of the key to determine if it exists.  The modified hash code didn't exist in the map, so it didn't even get to try the step of using the `equals` method.  That's why it's a bad idea to change your key objects while they're in a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 7):

This is explicitly documented in the `Map` Javadoc as dangerous and unlikely to work:

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined on such a map.